# Any way to disable popover dragging?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm creating an application, that uses webview. My first webview (the main one), is used just for a simple website. However, when I click on a certain link I open an interactive map (also in a webview). I'd love to open new webview as a popover, which I'm successful at by:

```
    let storyboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PopoverViewController")
    vc.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
    let popover: UIPopoverPresentationController = vc.popoverPresentationController!
    present(vc, animated: true, completion:nil)
```

But this webview contains map, which requires some user gestures like swipes and so on. But popover also reacts to the very same gestures and moves as well, which is not the behavior I want. Is there any way to stick the position of a popover, so it wouldn't respond for user's gestures?

Comment: Is this about the built in drag-down-to-dismiss functionality?

Comment: Exactly! All about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can remove

```swift
vc.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
```

as it is basically the same as the default modal presentation anchored to an existing view.

Then you can achieve this by disabling the default gesture recognizer that was used for drag-down-to-dismiss:

```swift
// Modify your last line...
present(vc, animated: true, completion: {
    // Disable drag gesture recognizer
    vc.presentationController?.presentedView?.gestureRecognizers?[0].isEnabled = false
})
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you! Works perfectly fine.

Comment: Glad to hear it